# How to configure urxvt to display Unicode characters?

Tags: fonts, unicode, rxvt

I've already looked at three sources ([1](https://superuser.com/q/509950), [2](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=229722), [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/323853/3645)) with no luck. I've tried launching `urxvt -fn 'xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:size=9'` and `urxvt -fn xft:FontAwesome`. A lot of characters show up properly, but [characters like "नमस्ते"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch08-02-strings.html#strings) show up as squares only:

[image: Unicode rendered in urxvt]

Strangely, the IntelliJ IDEA configuration says it's using *the same font* and there *the same string* displays fine:

[image: Unicode rendered in IDEA]

Does IDEA use some sort of fallback font for unknown glyphs, or is my configuration wrong?

```
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
$ xrdb -query
URxvt.background:   gray5
URxvt.color0:   Black
URxvt.color1:   Red3
URxvt.color10:  SpringGreen1
URxvt.color11:  Yellow
URxvt.color12:  RoyalBlue1
URxvt.color13:  Magenta
URxvt.color14:  Cyan
URxvt.color15:  White
URxvt.color2:   Green3
URxvt.color3:   Yellow3
URxvt.color4:   Blue3
URxvt.color5:   Magenta3
URxvt.color6:   Cyan3
URxvt.color7:   AntiqueWhite
URxvt.color8:   Grey25
URxvt.color9:   Red
URxvt.font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:pixelsize=42
URxvt.foreground:   gray80
URxvt.scrollBar:    false
URxvt.scrollTtyKeypress:    true
URxvt.scrollTtyOutput:  false
URxvt.scrollWithBuffer: true
URxvt.secondaryScreen:  true
URxvt.secondaryScroll:  false
$ xset q
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  660    repeat rate:  25
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fedfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x22    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/misc/,/usr/share/fonts/TTF/,/usr/share/fonts/OTF/,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 7200    Suspend: 7200    Off: 14400
  DPMS is Disabled
```

Comment: This is almost always a font problem.  Here's what works for me with `xterm`: `-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso10646-1`.  Other sizes of the same font don't work.